# Covariant return types in function pointers

Tags: rust, function-pointers, covariance

I want to have a safe function pointer that can point to a function that returns a more derived trait. Here is a simplified example of what I would like to accomplish which mimics what I'm looking to do in my actual code.

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/8bns6KaEa

```rust
trait Animal {}
trait Mamal: Animal {}

struct Cat {}

impl Animal for Cat{}
impl Mamal for Cat {}

fn main() {
    let function: fn() -> Box<dyn Animal> = return_cat;
}

fn return_cat() -> Box<dyn Mamal> {
    Box::new(Cat{})
}
```

This of course doesn't compile because the function `return_cat` is returning a `Box<dyn Mamal>` and the function pointer signature is expecting `Box<dyn Animal>`.

This isn't technically a case of covariant return types since the return type is actually `Box` and rather I want the generic parameter of `Box` to be covariant in this case.

Any way to get this to compile in Rust or do I need to completely rethink my solution?

Comment: You will need to rethink your solution. You will likely want to use the `Fn` trait and closures to handle different function variations.

Comment: Can you add a conversion step?